# TableViewCellをクリックして生成されたViewController上のラベルにCellのテキストを表示させる方法

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

https://akira-watson.com/iphone/tableview_3_objective-c.html 
上記サイトは、TableViewCell(以下、Cellとします）をクリックすることでViewControllerを 
生成してそこに遷移し、ViewController上のImageViewに画像を表示させるコードを紹介しています。 
表示される画像というのは、plistに格納されており、Cellをクリックすることで呼び出されます。 
plistには、テキストデータも含まれています。テキストデータは、Cellのテキストとして動的に表示されています。

上記サイトを参考にして、Cellをクリックして生成されたViewController上に貼り付けたラベルに、 
Cellのテキストを表示させる方法を模索しています。 
そのためには上記サイトのコードのうち、何箇所かを書き換えなければいけませんが、

```
//ViewController.hの中身
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property NSString *imageName;
@property IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

を

```
//ViewController.hの中身
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property NSString *textName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbText;
```

に書き換え、また、

```
// ViewController.mの中身
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageName];
    // 画像のアスペクト比を維持しUIImageViewサイズに収まるように表示
    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}
```

というコードのうち、

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageName];
```

を、画像ではなくテキストを表示させるものにしたいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？
とりあえず試しにこんなものを書いてみたのですが・・・

```
self.lbLabel.text = [UITextFieldLabel textNamed:self.textName];
```

当然動きません。

以上、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,100,200,30)];
label.text = self.textName;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

これでどうでしょうか？

追記：
上記はIBOutletを使わずにコード上でUILabelを生成して、UIViewControllerの持つプロパティ"view"に貼り付けただけです。画面に何も出ない場合の原因としては色々考えられますが、
例えば、

> ・上記コードの後の処理で貼り付けたUILabelの上に別のViewを被せて貼り付けている。
>   ・ViewControllerクラスに画面遷移していない。 
>   ・self.textNameに値が入っていない。など

ログを出す場合は下記のようにすると良いかもしれません。

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // 何か処理をすることがあればここで...

    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> textName : %@",self.textName);
    NSLog(@"views : %@",[self.view performSelector:@selector(recursiveDescription)]);  // リリース時は消すこと
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、変化はありませんでした。

Comment: @inu shiba 少し追記しました。

Comment: すみません、コードで生成したラベルが実際の画面の中に見当たらないのですが、どの辺りに貼り付けられるのでしょうか？
画面遷移はできています。ただ、self.textNameのログを取ると、NULLを吐き出していました。

Comment: @inu shiba ラベル生成時のコードを追記。通常なら赤色のViewが表示されると思います。ラベルの配置はテキトーです。textNameに値が入っていない理由はここまでの情報ではわかりません。

Comment: お手数をおかけしました。自己解決しました。ありがとうございました。